# Pass System .Property name as function parameter

Tags: c#

I want to create a function which stores some value within

System.Property.Default.my_property.

```
void foo(property_name, string property_value)
{
System.Property.Default.property_name = property_value;
}
```

Calls would look like this

```
foo(my_first_prop, "first");
foo(my_second_prop, "second")
```

What would be the bast way to do this?

Comment: Please use correct spelling and check your question before submitting it.

Comment: Why is this helpful or useful when `MyClass.FirstProp = "first"` is not only cleaner and less ambiguous but also less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `'property_name'` should be a string, then you can call it like this:

```
void foo(string property_name, string property_value)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default[property_name] = property_value;
}
```